# Akka Authentication with REST Http

Tags: scala, rest, akka

I'm testing Json HTTP Routes with Akka Basic Authentication and scala. But the routes don't work as needed. Here is the code

First the secured route is not working with postman BasicAuth. I need to add an email"secured/test@test.com" to trigger the logged in action. Second the subroute basketactor is not working at all. Postman says unknown Route. So how can i make this work with Postman BasicAuth Http Header? What kind of request do i have to send just "secured or with email and password together.
Second how can i make the subroutes basketActor/add work.

```
~ Route.seal {
          (pathPrefix("secured") & get) {
            authenticateBasic(realm = "secure site", myUserPassAuthenticator) { email =>
              path(Segment) { segment =>
                var user = User.USER_LIST.find(_.id == segment)
                if (user.isDefined)
                  complete(s"Hi '$email' you logged in")
                else complete(s"login failed Please register at ${"users" / "register"}")
              }
            } ~ path("basketActor") {
              (pathEnd & get) {
                implicit val timeout = Timeout(3 seconds)
                onSuccess((basketActor ? GetBasketProducts).mapTo[BasketList]) { res =>
                  complete(BasketContainer(products = res.products))
                }
              } ~ (path("add" / IntNumber) & post) { number =>
                val product = Product.PRODUCT_LIST.find(_.id == number)
                if (product.isDefined) {
                  product.foreach { product =>
                    basketActor ! AddProductToBasket(product)
                    //            complete(Basket.BASKET_LIST ::= product)
                  }
                  complete(product)
                } else complete("Not found")
              }
            }
          }
      }
```

```
 def myUserPassAuthenticator(credentials: Credentials): Option[String] =
      credentials match {
        case p@Credentials.Provided(id) if p.verify("secret") => Some(id)
        case _ => None
      }
```

So my expected result should be the user calls the secured Route logs in and then he can access the basketActor route. But now the route is not accessible and the secured route is also not working

Comment: I would start by fixing the secured route and then look at the other routes.

Comment: I would agree with Tim, first make the secured route work. Make sure you're using GET in postman (I think it's a GET request right?) and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Basic Authentication works in Akka HTTP:

The `Authorization` header in an HTTP Request is used for Basic Authentication, and it contains a username and password encoded using `base64` encoding. The `authenticateBasic` route will extract this information from the header to create a `Credentials` object, and then pass this to your `myUserPassAuthenticator` method. This method should check that the username and password match and if it succeeds it should return an object representing that user in your system, or return `None` on failure.

The second (curried) argument to `authenticateBasic` is a function that takes the user data and returns a `Route`. So in your case the `email` argument will contain the `id` value returned by `myUserPassAuthenticator`. This function should return a route that contains all the paths that require authentication.

---

It is important to realise that there is no concept of being "logged in" with Basic Authentication. There are just authentication credentials that are either correct or incorrect. (If you want to have login/logout semantics you need to move to a token-based authentication mechanism).

---

So to make your routes work you need to move the logic that looks-up a user ID into `myUserPassAuthenticator` and return the `user` object as the result. As it happens you can just return the result of `find` because this already returns an `Option[User]`.

You also need to make sure that all the authenticated routes are inside the `authenticateBasic` route. Currently the `basketActor` and `add` routes are at the same level and therefore are not authenticated.

---

A sample route would look like this. I have used `concat` rather than `~` as I think it is clearer.

```
pathPrefix("secured") {
  authenticateBasic(realm = "secure site", myUserPassAuthenticator) { user =>
    concat(
      (pathEnd | pathSingleSlash) {
        get {
          complete(s"User $user Authenticated OK")
        }
      },
      path("basketActor") {
        (pathEnd & get) {
          complete(s"basketActor for $user")
        }
      },
      path("add" / IntNumber) { number =>
        post {
          complete(s"User $user posted $number")
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Note that the user ID (email address) is not in the URL, it is in the request in the `Basic Authentication` header.

To test this with Postman you need to go create a `GET` with the URL `.../secured` or `.../secured/basketActor`, or a  `POST` with the URL `.../secured/add/1`. Under the `Auth` tab you need to select `Basic Authentication` and add the credentials there.

Comment: Hi @Tim, first thanks for your answer, but i have more questions
1st when i fire the first request GET http://localhost:8083/secured it says the The requested resource could not be found. so how must the request look like f.e. GET http://localhost:8083/secured/test@email/secret can you give maybe some example code

Comment: @EddyEddy I had added some sample code to my answer. The email and password do not go in the URL, they go in the `Authorization` field of the HTTP request. You can use the Postman `Auth` tab to add this information to a request.